# Edit website content from web.

Tags: html, drupal, dynamic

I have a friend that I'm running a website for. When he needs to change text, he has to go through me, and I'm busy, so he has to wait. He has no knowledge of HTML, but I would like to set it up so he can go to a certain page, log in, and edit the page's text at least. I'm thinking maybe to try drupal?

Comment: yeah go for CMS as they are especially for those who want to have their own website but dunno about Web Development or Designing but want to have content on it regular basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solutions would be  a CMS like drupal, wordpress or joomla. I have found wordpress to be one of the easiest to use. Once its set up changes are done in a flash.